# Using Pivot Table for Overtime Data with additional Trend Analysis columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel worksheet that has Overtime (OT) data for each person in the company summarized per pay period. My objectives in Excel are as follows:

1. Show a current pay period summary of OT hours by department (sorted with most hours at top); If the solution is within the PivotTable it would be nice to ONLY show the current pay period (and applicable trend averages) if possible
2. Provide simple trend data (4 pay period AVG and YTD AVG) to make the current pay period data more relevant.
3. Make the analysis/tool/table easy to refresh by simply adding new rows to raw data; this will be provided to an HR admin so it must be user-friendly for updating every time period.

[Current Raw Data Screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7kAE.jpg)

[Current PivotTable Screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEvOr.jpg)

Ideally, the user could select the current pay period, and that would display the OT sum for the current pay period and the two averages mentioned above.  From there, I would add conditional formatting to improve the UI for the managers/end users of the data.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately the community here will not normally write code from scratch - you really need to do some research, have a go, and then post here when you get stuck.

Comment: Hi MandyShaw, thanks for the info. I guess I was looking more for method/approach advice in Excel.  I can get the trend calcs but refreshing/updating is where I ran into issues.  Essentially data manipulation of PivotTable data.

Comment: Unfortunately you would not usually find that sort of advice provided on StackOverflow. it's more intended as a source of help on very specific problems in code that is under development.

Comment: Try posting over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thanks PeterT!  I'll try there and maybe Mr. Excel.